# Regular expression to match a phrase, accepting a minimal amount of characters

Tags: .net, regex

I would like a regular expression that, starting at the beginning of the text, matches a word. If the exact word is typed it matches, but will also match a certain minimal number of matching characters, **provided that any additional characters also match**.

For example, if I am trying to match "San Francisco," but am willing to accept the first five characters as sufficient to identify it uniquely in the domain:

- *Match:* **San Francisco**
- *Match:* **San F**
- *Match:* **San Fra**
- *Match:* **San Francisco**blahblah
- *Fail:* Boston
- *Fail:* San Diego
- *Fail:* San Fransisko
- *Fail:* San Frano

This *almost* works, but incorrectly matches the last two:

```
^San Fr?a?n?c?i?s?c?o?
```

I'm using .NET regular expressions, but a solution in any language will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're having is one of grouping.

```
^San F(r(a(n(c(i(s(c(o)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?
```

The parentheses will make it so that 'a' being allowed is dependent on a preceding 'r', and so forth.  It will still match on 'San Frano' and 'San Fransisko', but the matches will only be 'San Fran', similar to your 'San Fransiscoblahblah' case.

Answer (score 4):

Does it have to be a regex? It's much easier to do with a straightforward string comparison.

```
bool matches(string input, string phrase, int minimumLength)
{
    int compareLength = Math.Min(input.Length, phrase.Length);
    return input.Length >= minimumLength
        && input.Substring(0, compareLength ) == phrase.Substring(0, compareLength );
}
```

If it does have to be a regex then...

```
"^San F(r(a(n(c(i(s(c(o.*)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$"
```

Answer (score 0):

If it needs to be a RegEx then this will work:

```
(^San Fr)(ancisco.*|ancisc|ancis|anci|anc|an|a)?\b
```

Where

> **x|y** - Matches either x or y. For example, "z|wood" matches "z" or
>   "wood". "(z|w)oo" matches "zoo" or "wood".
>
> **\b** - Matches a word boundary, that is, the position between a word and a space. For example, "er\b" matches the "er" in "never" but not
>   the "er" in "verb".

This will result in the match being the entire phrase - if there is a match. And no partial matches for things like `San Frano`.

You can play with the [above example at Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vvph):

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need here is not a simple Regex, but a method to calculate the distance or even similarity of 2 given strings?

If so look at Levenstein algoritm to calculate the distance between strings.

Does that help?